# 例外処理について

Tags: ruby

requireで外部ファイルを読み込み、送信ミスでエラーコードとメッセージが返って生きた場合の例外処理をしたい場合どうすればいいのでしょうか。

数値を設定し送信した時に、num=0.123とするところを間違えてnum=0.1234と小数点以下の桁数を間違えて送信してしまった場合に、
testを実行すると

> p test
>    # "code"=>-1111, "msg"=>"Precision is over the maximum defined for this
>   asset."

と最大値を超えていますと返ってきた場合に、例外処理を書き桁数を減らしてリトライしたいのですが例外処理の書き方がよくわかりません。

基本的な事ですが教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。コードを載せようと思ったのですが、apiキー等が必要な為載せませんでした。申し訳ありません。ふっとこれはプログラムのエラーではなくサーバー側のエラーなのでifメソッドでいけるのではないかと思い、試したところなんとか上手くいきそうです。回答して下さりありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rubyの例外処理をするコードは、以下のような感じで書きます。

```
begin
    # 例外が起こるかも知れないコード
rescue => error # 変数(例外オブジェクトの代入)
    # 例外が発生した時のコード
end
```

beginの次からrescueの手前までに書かれたコードが実行されて、例外が発生しなければ終わり。
例外が起きたら、その例外オブジェクトが　rescue=> で指定した変数(上の例では error)に代入されます。
そして、rescueの次からendの手前までのコードで例外を処理します。

＝アドバイス＝
　p test で実行されるプログラムのコードを質問に追加してください。そうすれば、もっと具体的な助言をしてもらえると思います。